# goroutine out put to channel order fixed?

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func sum(a []int, c chan int) {
    sum := 0
    for _, v := range a {
        sum += v
    }
    c <- sum // send sum to c
}

func main() {
    a := []int{7, 2, 8, -9, 4, 0}

    c := make(chan int)
    go sum(a[len(a)/2:], c)
    go sum(a[:len(a)/2], c)

    x, y := <-c, <-c // receive from c

    fmt.Println(x, y, x+y)
}
```

`x, y := <-c, <-c // receive from c`

Why does this line always print the same result?

I think it should be 50/50 chance to print
`17 -5 12`
or
`-5 17 12`

I think the two go routines should be parallel

Thanks in advance!

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"
import "math/rand"

func sum(a []int, c chan int) {
    sum := 0
    for _, v := range a {
        sum += v
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * time.Duration(rand.Intn(1000)))
    c <- sum // send sum to c

}

func main() {
    a := []int{7, 2, 8, -9, 4, 0}

    c := make(chan int)
    go sum(a[len(a)/2:], c)
    go sum(a[:len(a)/2], c)

    x, y := <-c, <-c // receive from c

    fmt.Println(x, y, x+y)
}
```

I make the thread to sleep, but same thing happens. I am still confusing.

Comment: Are you using Go 1.5? Also how many cores?

Comment: @Shawn Putting the sleep at the end of the function like that will not have the effect you are looking for. Furthermore, the main function doesn't wait for the sleep to finish executing before terminating, so the sleep is essentially doing nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption that it *should* be a 50/50 chance is incorrect in this situation. To be clear, I'm not suggesting it should always be one or the other but rather that you shouldn't expect it to change each time the program runs. The behavior is not necessarily random (or even pseudo-random).

A goroutine's guarantee is not that it will be scheduled at a random future time, but rather just that it will run at some time in the future. If the current implementation of the scheduler decided to put goroutines in a simple queue, it wouldn't automatically mean it's broken. For your particular code's case, if you stick a few `time.Sleep`s or `fmt.Printf`s in different places, you'd likely see the order change around sometimes.

I wonder if you're confusing Go's scheduler's selection of the next goroutine with the documented pseudo-random behavior of `select` when used with channels. The behavior there is defined to be random and it's correct to say the behavior *should* have a 50/50 chance.

As far as I've read, the choice of which goroutine the runtime will select is not random. That's not the same as saying it can't be random, but moreso that it's not *supposed* to be random.

The important thing is that your code shouldn't care about the order in which goroutines are scheduled. Whether it's always in order like a queue, or backwards (a stack), or random, or something else (likely the reality).

Comment: I make the thread to sleep, but same thing happens. I am still confusing.

Comment: @Shawn you put the sleep after the value is placed on the channel, this will not have the effect you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. Even I put the sleep before send number to channel same thing happens again....

Comment: @Shawn Now you just have a different problem. You need to seed the pseudo-random number generator. Otherwise you are seeing the *same* "random" numbers every time. Add `rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())` to the top of your `main` function and it will work.